# How to include all levels in Unreal Engine build

Tags: game-engine, unreal-engine4

I have 10 levels, open each new using OpenLevel function from my level logic actor. Actually i understand that having special actor (blueprint) on scene, that contain logic is no good, but didn't fint other way how to do certain things. I think that's not a problem itself.

So when i play game in editor, eveything is fine, i got transition into new level, when i call OpenLevel function.

But when i build game, there is only 1 level. How i supposed to include all levels in build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for:
Edit -> Project Settings -> Packaging -> List of maps to include in a packaged build
[List of maps to include in a packaged build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZKWN.png)

https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?73136-Generic-Shooter-Support-Thread/page4

Comment: Thanks, i have got it already. Now i have another problems, as usually. :) My build broken, it just hangs and game doesn't start, have to revise build logs, it says it's successfull, but there are a lot of warnings.